# Image from S3 bucket does not display on server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm facing a weird issue on S3 bucket, I'm using S3 bucket to store images for the application and lambda to handle API functions, so the upload works correctly on local and also using lambda, the issue is when I want to show the image on the app, on localhost works great but on server the image does not show at all:

Here is on local: https://www.screencast.com/t/GA9R2ik3vX

But on server looks like this: https://www.screencast.com/t/oSY2AuE5NF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking it could be a problem with your policy settings for the S3 bucket access. It may be that when setting up the bucket AWS obtained your local IP and added it to the allowed IPs list (I'm pretty sure AWS does this automatically sometimes) and that's why it works on your localhost but not on your server.

Make sure your block public access looks like this:
[image]

And that your bucket policy is public:

[image]

It should look something like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt123",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that this will make images in your bucket public and anyone with a link will have access to it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried that and same result, images does not load correctly, I don't know maybe I'm missing something on my serverless config file or some configuration on my lambda.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FIX**

The problem is still there but I found a different way to upload the image, I did it from the front end side instead of the lambda using a signed url, hope it help someone in the future.